# Arduino import jquery file

Tags: javascript, jquery, arduino

У меня есть рабочий код для esp8266 в котором jquery импортируется из интернета, но мне нужно импортировать его из скачанного файла и у меня это никак не получается. Когда я пишу #include "jquery-3.5.1.min.js", оно выдаёт ошибку: jquery-3.5.1.min.js: No such file or directory( Так же оно выдаёт эту ошибку если я указываю полный путь). Хотя этот файл находится в той же директории что и файл проекта. Подскажите пожалуйста что я делаю не так?

Весь код:

```cpp
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <DNSServer.h>
#include <ESP8266WebServer.h>
#include "jquery-3.5.1.min.js"


const byte DNS_PORT = 53;
IPAddress apIP(172, 0, 0, 1);
DNSServer dnsServer;
ESP8266WebServer webServer(80);


String handleRoot = R"=====(
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
   <head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'>\
  </head>
  <body>
      <h1>Ввод:</h1>
      <input type='text' name='input' id='input' size=2 autofocus>
      <div>
      <br><button id='save_button'>Send</button>
      </div>
<script src="/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
  var input;
  $('#save_button').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    input = $('#input').val();
    $.get('/send?input=' + input, function(data){
     console.log(data);
    });
  });   
</script>
</body>
</html>
)=====";

void handleSend() {
  if (webServer.arg("input")!= ""){
    Serial.println("Input is: " + webServer.arg("input"));
  }
}


void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  delay(10);
  Serial.println("Started");
  WiFi.mode(WIFI_AP);
  WiFi.softAPConfig(apIP, apIP, IPAddress(255, 255, 255, 0));
  WiFi.softAP("INFO");
  
  dnsServer.start(DNS_PORT, "*", apIP);

  webServer.onNotFound([]() {
   webServer.send(200, "text/html", handleRoot);
  });
   webServer.on ("/send", handleSend);
  webServer.begin();
}

void loop() {
  dnsServer.processNextRequest();
  webServer.handleClient();
}
```

Comment: Не нужно делать `#include "jquery-3.5.1.min.js"` - так можно подключать только заголовочные файлы C/C++. Вместо этого нужно прописать, чтобы при обращении к `/jquery-3.5.1.min.js` ваш вебсервер возвращал этот файл клиентской стороне.

Comment: Точнее даже скорее всего придется его вставить в код так же как html, и возвращать его при обращении к `/jquery-3.5.1.min.js` по аналогии с тем, как возвращается handleRoot. Только не факт что у вас прошивка с js файлом влезет на arduino.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! По идее оно должно вместиться, у этой платы 4мб памяти, а файл js, весит 87кб.

Comment: Ну значит должно влезть по идее